# Total mês a mês que some com meses anteriores

Tags: mysql

Preciso de um `SELECT`que traga a soma de dados mês a mês e some com o total dos meses anteriores.

No `SELECT` abaixo está trazendo a soma mês a mês.

```
SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(data_pgto_bx) as mes, SUM(total_bx) FROM gc_baixas
WHERE sit_bx = 3 GROUP BY mes ORDER BY mes ASC
```

Até aí tudo bem com o `SELECT` acima, o meu problema é um pouco mais complexo, preciso que este `SELECT` também some a coluna `total_bx` com os meses anteriores. Exemplo:

- No mês 10 traga a soma da coluna `total_bx` de todos os meses até o
  mês 10;
- No mês 11 traga a soma de todos os meses até o mês 11;

Comment: No SQL Server temos [funções de classificação](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189798.aspx) para fazer isso. No MySQL infelizmente isso não existe. Terá que usar alguma lógica usando variáveis. Mais tarde tentarei responder sua pergunta.

Comment: Só para esclarecer, você precisa a soma parcial mensalmente, certo?

Comment: Não Thomas, preciso da soma total até o mês, sendo que este select deverá mostrar mês a mês com o total geral até o mês.

Comment: @IrioBroleisFilho ou seja, um campo que informe a soma parcial do mês, e que retorne isso no período mês a mês (mensalmente)

Comment: Obrigado @Thomas. A resposta do Omni supriu a minha necessidade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como o [@gmsantos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4751/gmsantos) confirmou nao existem funções analíticas disponíveis em `MySQL`. A solução então passa por correr uma `query` dentro da `query` principal que calcule os resultados necessários mês a mês:

```
SET @totalagregado := 0;
SELECT 
 resultados_mes.mes as mes,
 resultados_mes.soma_mes as soma_mes,
 (@totalagregado := @totalagregado + resultados_mes.soma_mes) as soma_agregada
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(data_pgto_bx) as mes, SUM(total_bx) as soma_mes
  FROM gc_baixas
  WHERE sit_bx = 3 
  GROUP BY mes
  ORDER BY mes ASC  
) as resultados_mes
```

[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80dfc/6).

O resultado desta `query` terá o seguinte formato:

> Mês | Total do mês | Total agregado
>
> 1   | 1234         | 1234
>
> 2   | 1234          | 2468
>
> ...

Comment: Perfeito Omni, era isto que eu estava precisando. Obrigado.